# Can a TCP packet with the FIN flag also have data?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm working on a packet capture program. Is it possible for TCP packet to have the FIN flag set but also have data?

Comment: Yes indeed, in in fact it is very likely if the close immediately follows the last send.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it is possible to put data in a `TCP FIN` packet... Quoting from [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-26) (emphasis mine):

> The SYN and FIN
> are the only controls requiring this protection, and these controls
> are used only at connection opening and closing.  For sequence number
> purposes, the SYN is considered to occur before the first actual data
> octet of the segment in which it occurs, **while the FIN is considered
> to occur after the last actual data octet in a segment in which it
> occurs**.