# Acknowledge number of piggy backing fin?

Tags: tcp

I'm implementing simple TCP stack.

In close, I know that fin packet have +1 ack.

ex) send fin(seq:10), the receive ack(ack:11)

I have two questions.

1. Does fin packet can be sent with data?(piggy back)
2. If so, how can I calculate ack number?

ex) send fin+data(seq:10, data_len:10), then receive ack(ack:21) not ack(ack:20)?

have a nice day!

Comment: Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702646/packet-capture-can-a-packet-with-the-fin-flag-also-have-data

Comment: @Prabhu Thank you!